# Reprojecting GeoTIFF from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 with GDAL

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp

As an example I am using the following GeoTIFF image: [BlackMarble_2016_3km_geo.tif - 61 MB - GeoTIFF](https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/images/144898/earth-at-night-black-marble-2016-color-maps)

I am trying to reproject from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 with the following GDAL command:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857 BlackMarble_2016_3km_geo.tif reprojected.tif
```

The resulting image is stretched vertically and has a resolution of 1243 x 15042

I am however able to get a correctly reprojected image if I also specify the extents via this modified command:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs epsg:3857 -te -20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34  BlackMarble_2016_3km_geo.tif reprojected.tif
```

this results in a image resolution of 13104 x 13104 (square)

Why do I need to supply the extents via `-te` to `gdalwarp` if for example when I use `gdalinfo` it outputs the `cornerCoordinates` ["-180, 90", "-180, -90", "180, 90", "180, -90"] of the original file (EPSG:4326), why does it fail to automatically reproject correctly to EPSG:3857? And I am aware that EPSG:3857's bounds are `[-85.06,-180,85.06,180]`.

Comment: My GDAL behaves in a different way with your original command `Creating output file that is 9105P x 12038L.` and pixel size is `Pixel Size = (4401.387397656880239,-4401.387397656880239)`. My version is 3.4.0dev.

Comment: It seems that my GDAL also goes beyond the EPSG:3857 limits, upper corners in the result are 88d12' 0.00"N and lower ones  88d12' 0.66"S. So maybe this version does a bit better job for fitting and cropping the result to valid area of EPSG:3857 but not at all perfect. The image still behaves well when opened with QGIS. So is your question why there is no automatic clipping to the valid area of EPSG:3857? I do know that in real work it is necessary to be able to go pass the official limits for example if user has data from both sides of the border between UTM zones.

Comment: If you cannot get an answer here I suggest to write mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask. My guess is that gdalwarp tries not to throw away valid data from the source if the transformation into the new CRS is mathematically possible. I believe that the pixels in your first, very high image, are correctly reprojected and they appear in the right place on the map.